# How to set the Emacs title bar like "plugin.el@~/.emacs.d/plugin/"

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

I wanna to set my title bar like `plugin.el@~/.emacs.d/plugin/`
, the plugin.el file is in the plugin directory, I googled a lot, no result just is like what I need.

1. the order of file name and directory name
2. change /home/username to ~ if the file is in my home directory
3. the string after `@` is just directory name without the file name

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`frame-title-format`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frame-Titles.html) to something like `(:eval (let ((b (buffer-file-name))) (format "%s@%s" (file-name-nondirectory b) (file-name-directory b))))`.

Maybe what you are actually looking for is a different [uniquification policy](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html), though. This will affect the mode line, the actual buffer names, and (in many standard configurations) the frame title.

Comment: Thank you, very close, but change the HOME to ~, please

Comment: The links I included are insufficient for figuring that out? Wrap the directory part in [`abbreviate-file-name`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Names.html#Directory-Names). Maybe still not 100% there but then this is a programming help site, not a free coding service.